# Output with different data types?

Tags: java, types

I coded something just for fun and found something very confusing.

I first code something like this.

```
public class Testing(){
  public static void main(String args[]){
     int a=1;
     char b='A';
     System.out.print('A'+a);
        }
}
```

The output is 66?

Then I modify the second code like this.

```
public class Testing(){
      public static void main(String args[]){
         int a=1;
         char b='A';
         System.out.print((char)('A'+a));
            }
    }
```

The output of the second code is B.

Can someone help me to explain wha happens here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
 System.out.print('A'+a);
```

'A' will be used as a number(it is a truncated integer actually) and the result will be represented as a number...

when you do:

```
 System.out.print((char)('A'+a));
```

you are casting that into a char so the result will be what ever in the ascii is mapped to 66

Answer (score 0):

When you add a `char` and an `int` (as in `'A'+a`), the `char` is promoted to an `int`, and the result is an `int`.

Therefore the first snippet prints an `int`.

In the second snippet you cast that `int` to `char`, so the character `'B'`, whose `int` value is `66`, is displayed.

Your two snippets call different methods of `PrintStream` - the first converts an `int` to a `String` and the second converts a `char` to a `String`:

```
/**
 * Prints an integer.  The string produced by <code>{@link
 * java.lang.String#valueOf(int)}</code> is translated into bytes
 * according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes
 * are written in exactly the manner of the
 * <code>{@link #write(int)}</code> method.
 *
 * @param      i   The <code>int</code> to be printed
 * @see        java.lang.Integer#toString(int)
 */
public void print(int i) {
    write(String.valueOf(i));
}

/**
 * Prints a character.  The character is translated into one or more bytes
 * according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes
 * are written in exactly the manner of the
 * <code>{@link #write(int)}</code> method.
 *
 * @param      c   The <code>char</code> to be printed
 */
public void print(char c) {
    write(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

Comment: In the first code, after casting char to int, the output should be int as well then, but why does it come up with 66 rather other numbers, like 43, 56. Is there a casting list, like ASCII? Thanks!

Comment: @littletony `char` is an numeric type, so each character has a numeric value. The numeric value of 'A' is 65. 65 + 1 is 66.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Internally, char is an integer value mapped to a character symbol. That's why you can add it to an int. If you tell Java to handle the result as a char, you get a char.

Answer (score 0):

In the case `'A'+a` the operation considered as integer addition and the char converted to its equivalent ASCII number. Hence the result is an integer.

In case 2 happened the same thing and the final output converted to `char` from its ASCII since you casted.

Comment: so integer 1 stands for alphet A, and 2 stands for B, and so on and so forth? Thanks!